# PDO update query with brackets

Tags: php, pdo, brackets

I want to execute such query:

```
UPDATE users SET online_time = (online_time + 50) WHERE ID = 1
```

I have a problem because online_time does not update, it is replaced by 0.
In mysqli everything was OK.
This is my code for update function in database class (it is from internet, not my work):

```
public function update($table, $data, $where)
{
    ksort($data);

    $fieldDetails = null;
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $fieldDetails .= "$key=:$key, ";
    }
    $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ', ');

    $sth = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value){
        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }
    $sth->execute();
}
```

and code i am trying to run:

```
$set = ['online_time' => "(online_time + $t)"];
$where = 'ID = '. $id;
$this->db->update('users', $set, $where);
```

It is probably something wrong with update function but I do not know what :/

Comment: do you receive any errors ?

Comment: however you will encounter a problem , because in your foreach loop : `"$key=:$key, "` so after adding your `$set` variable it will be something like this: `online_time=:(online_time + $t)`

Comment: `$sth = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where");` this looks dangerous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and foremost problem with your update function is that it's [prone to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example).

And yes, it is not suitable for updating with complex expressions like this.

So for this particular query simply avoid this function and run just a raw prepared statement

```
$sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET online_time = online_time + ? WHERE ID = ?");
$sth->execute([$t, $id]);
```